# Compare values in two strings and then yield a result that can be placed in an array

Tags: python, arrays, string, compare

I have two strings in python that I have converted to lists:

```
Seq1 = [x1,x2,x3,x4]

Seq2 = [y1,y2,y3,y4]
```

The strings are the same length and are composed of only the letters `'a'`, `'c'`, `'g'`, and `'u'`.

Then I created an empty matrix `len(Seq1)` by `len(Seq2)`:

```
a = numpy.zeros(shape=len(Seq1),len(Seq2))
```

Next, I want to compare the list values and place a `1` if the values match and `0` if they don't. The value should be placed in the relevant array element
i.e.

```
if seq1[0] == seq[0]:
    a[0,0] = [1]
else:
    a[0,0] = [0]

# repeat for all the values.
print a
```

I had a loop that was working but it only filled in the first row and column. I can see that it's a problem with a range function like `Seq1[i] == Seq2[j]` but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Hi, Matthew. This will be most constructive if you edit the post to include code of what you have tried (i.e., the defunct loop you refer to at the end) and ask a question based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A compact way to write the loop is:

```
import itertools

for i1,i2 in itertools.product(xrange(len(Seq1)), xrange(len(Seq2))):
    a[i1,i2] = Seq1[i1] == Seq2[i2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over both lists and compare:

```
for x in range(len(Seq1)):
  for y in range(len(Seq2)):
    a[x, y] = (Seq1[x] == Seq2[y])
```

Comment: this is brilliant thank you so much! I knew it was simple I just couldn't get my head around it :)

Comment: You did not really have to convert them to lists.  The exact same code works on strings too.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this is a bioinformatics question. The purpose, however, is unclear to me. I've listed a generic matching system that you can use.

```
>>> for s1 in xrange(len(seq1)):
...     for s2 in xrange(len(seq2)):
...             if seq1[s1]==seq2[s2]:
...                     a[s1,s2]=1
...             else:
...                     a[s1,s2]=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the nested loops at all; outer methods in numpy can do it for you:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86882M, Nov 30 2010, 10:35:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> seq1 = "acgu"
>>> seq2 = "aagg"
>>> numpy.equal.outer(map(ord, seq1), map(ord, seq2))
array([[ True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```